# Monotouch.Dialog MultiLineElement

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, monotouch.dialog

I am trying to create a MultiLineInputElement using Monotouch.Dialog.

I have taken the code from the InputElement class and modified it to use UITextView so that it will work.

No matter what I do to force the UITextView to size to more than one line nothing seems to affect it? I think it's because the parent row is limiting it?

Here is the code I have so far:

http://pastebin.com/NppqK6sE

Comment: Does your Root element have UnevenRows set? i.e Root.UnevenRows = true;

Answer (score 0):

I did this using SimpleMultilineEntryElement from https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-element-pack